# How to destroy the side menu before move?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, menu, side-menu

I use the side menu (jonkykong / SideMenu) when developing an application for iOS and ran into a problem. I need a menu that will be displayed on all ViewController, everything seems to work, but when you switch to the second controller, a new menu opens with the second controller, but the old menu. The only thing I found in the developer's questions is that it's necessary to destroy the old menu before switching to the second controller, but I have not found it anywhere. The code for my menu is exactly the same as in the example, except for the TableView in the menu itself (the list of menu items is implemented by tables) and the implementation of the standard functions of selecting on the table cell. I am hope for your help. Thank you very much.

Link to the side menu itself:
github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

[Photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgNwl.png)
[Photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7ZRo.png)

Comment: dont get you, you should explain with code or screenshot.

Comment: added photos for you

Comment: @Wolfak add your code as code, images are not the proper way to show your code please

Comment: @Reinier Melian code is on the menu Example!

Comment: There is property called  menuPushStyle make it  MenuPushStyle =.popWhenPossible